# when starting activity with web-view, screen blinks for long time

Tags: android, webview, garbage-collection

I have an activity with 5 WebViews and when this activity is loaded for the first time, the screen blinks continuously for about 1 to 2 minutes before it settles. I also noticed that during this period of blinking,  GC process is busy cleaning the memory.

Comment: Might help to give more information on what the web views are doing, any meta data being loaded, general app profiling might help to see which objects are being allocated in excess - as you mention GC pauses. This question is to vague to be answered.

Comment: also can you add to the tags - is this android or a regular web app or iOS ?

Comment: tgkprog, Thanks for the reply. I removed 5 webviews and managed with just one and everything seems working fine. Mine is an android app

Comment: good then you can answer you own question and mark it as the answer. so you went from 5 to 1 web view?

Comment: Yes. I moved from 5 to 1 that stopped screen flickering and also looks like WebView is a costly resource.

Comment: My suggestion is to add it as an answer (not a comment as you have now) - and then accept answer see [FAQ] for why  & [help] ...